# Unable to build job in jenkinsapi module in python

Tags: python, jenkins-api

I tried to build a job in jenkins using python jenkinsapi,
I tried passing nested dict as a parameter to build the job,

```
server = Jenkins(args.host,
                 username=jenkins_credentials['user'],
                 password=jenkins_credentials['key'],
                 ssl_verify=False)

server.build_job(job, {'VENOM_ENV': job_parameters['jenkins']['parameters']})
```

> ->`job_parameters['jenkins']['parameters']}`-> is a nested dictionary itself.

I am hitting the below error:

```
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, status=500, text=<html><head><title>Error</title><body>
<p>An error occurred processing your request. Ask your Jenkins administrator to look up details. ErrorID=bb2f5954-074d-437d-bb62-ecc0e3be5590</p>
<hr><a href="https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Suppress+Stack+Trace+Plugin">Stack trace suppressed by the suppress stack trace plugin</a>
</body></html>
```

When i checked with the jenkins team, they found the issue to be with the parameter passed:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal number of parameter values for VENOM_ENV: 21
```

Note:
I used same parameter with jenkins module of python, I do not see any issue there.

What I am missing?

Comment: Can someone take a look

Comment: we cant use nested dict for building jobs?